# Can we add a person with no SSN/ITIN to our credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, itin, ssn, authorized-user

If there is someone with F-1 student visa in the US and has a SSN and a credit card, can he/she add his/her spouse who has no SSN/ITIN to his/her credit card?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is “probably yes,” you probably will be allowed to do this. You’ll need to call up your credit card company/bank and talk to them about it, but I think it is likely that they will be able to add your spouse as an authorized user and send you a card with his or her name on it. You would still be the account holder and would still be ultimately responsible for the payments.